# GIT Ignore previously added folder

Tags: git

I have a folder logs/ which was added in .git 
There may be files and sub-folders as well inside logs/
I want to ignore everything inside logs/ but not the logs/ folder itself.

I found following command to remove previously added file:

```
git rm --cached filename
```

but not able to ignore files and folders inside logs/
I also tried git 
    rm --cached logs/*

but it shows all files inside it as deleted

but of no help :(

I simply want git to ignore everything inside logs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ignore everything inside a directory but not the directory itself, you might need to include at least one non-ignored file inside that directory.

For instance, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/932982), you could create a `.gitignore` file inside of that directory that contains:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

Then add that file to your repository. Now the directory will be kept but git will only keep track of the `.gitignore` file inside of it.

Comment: A README is also a good idea to tell everyone why the directory is empty